# Magento 1.9: Homepage Filterproducts

Tags: magento-1.9

I use below code to **show latest products on my homepage** as a **product carousel** but **sort function** doesn't work.

```
{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" product_count="6"
 category_id="171" sort_by="position" aspect_ratio="0" image_width="296"
 image_height="395" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

**I want to show products on the position that I have given on category page.**

`List.php` file under a`pp/code/local/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Latest/Home` has been changed but still doesn't work.

```
    $category_id = $this->getCategoryId();

    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    if($category_id) {
        /*$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);    

        $products = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($products)
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId);*/

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('position')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
    }
    else {
        $products = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($products)
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
    }
```

Do I need to change any other file? I'm using **Magento 1.9.1.0**
Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually code shows products on the position that I have given on category page but **product images and prices** are not displayed. Product image is coming as Magento default and price is coming as "0".

Comment: I found a solution by adding `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`